# What is the Poisson binomial probability, for one flip of one fair coin and two unfair coins with probability-of-heads $p_u$, of flipping $r$ heads?

Tags: probability, poisson-binomial-distribution

The binomial probability, for one flip of $n$ unfair coins with probability-of-heads $p_u$, of flipping $r$ heads
$$B(n, r, p) = C(n, r) \ p^r \ (q = 1 - p)^{n - r}$$

Answer (score 0):

1. Probability of having $0$ heads

The probability of having $0$ heads is $(q = 1 - p)^{2}*0.5$, since you have twice tail with a probability of $1-p$, and once tail with a probability of $0.5$.This quantity is equal to: $(1+p^2-2p)*0.5=0.5+0.5p^2-p$.

2. Probability of having $3$ heads

The probability of having $3$ heads is $p^{2}*0.5$, since you have twice head with a probability of $p$, and once head with a probability of $0.5$.

3. Probability of having $1$ head

The probabilities of having $1$ and $2$ tails are less straightforward.
There are two ways in which you can have $1$ head: either from the fair coin, or from the unfair one.
The probability in the former case is: $(q = 1 - p)^{2}*0.5$, since you have two tails that had a probability of $1-p$, and one head that had a probability of $0.5$. The probability in the latter case is: $(q = 1 - p)*p*2*0.5=(q = 1 - p)*p $, since you have two ways how you can have one head and one tail from the unfair coins, and the probability of tail from the fair coin is $0.5$. The probability is thus given by the sum, that is: $(q = 1 - p)^{2}*0.5+(q = 1 - p)*p =(1 - p)*(0.5-0.5p+p)=(1-p)*(0.5+0.5p)=(1-p)*0.5*(1+p)$. This quantity is equal to: $(1-p^2)*0.5=0.5-0.5p^2$.

4. Probability of having $2$ heads

There are two ways in which you can have 2 heads: either both from the unfair coins, or one from the fair coin and one from the unfair one.
The probability in the former case is: $p^{2}*0.5$, since you have two heads that had a probability of $p$, and one tail that had a probability of $0.5$. The probability in the latter case is the same as above, since you have again one head and one tail from the unfair coins, and the probability of head from the fair coin is equal to the one of head, that is $0.5$. The probability is thus given by the sum, that is: : $p^{2}*0.5+(q = 1 - p)*p=p*(0.5p+1-p)=p*(1-0.5p)$.This quantity is equal to: $p-0.5p^2$.

5. Checking the sum of probabilities

To check that the calculations are correct: the sum of the 4 probabilities is $0.5+0.5p^2-p+0.5p^{2}+0.5-0.5p^2+p-0.5p^2=0.5+0.5=1$.

6. General formula

Suppose you have $n_F$ fair tosses with probability of head $p$ and $n_U$ unfair ones. Then your formula becomes: $$B(n_U, n_F, r, p) = \sum_{j=max(0,r-n_F)}^{min(r,n_U)}C(n_U, j) \ p^j \ (q = 1 - p)^{n_U - j}*C(n_F, r-j)0.5^{r-j}*0.5^{n_F-(r-j)}$$=$$ \sum_{j=max(0,r-n_F)}^{min(r,n_U)}C(n_U, j) \ p^j \ (q = 1 - p)^{n_U - j}*C(n_F, r-j)*0.5^{n_F}$$